# Flow: how does it work?

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

How does flow work ? I don't understand what they did. For example, why in the edged marked by 3, in the solution it's written 1 ? Morover, a maximum flow is the number a flow or the then longest flow ?

[image]

Comment: could the downvoter explain his downvote ?

Comment: Other users than the downvoter themself can only speculate what was the reason for the downvote. But if you wish to discuss the reason for the downvote, there is a [chatroom explicitly for this purpose](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21818649#21818649).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A flow from $s$ to $t$ is an assignment of values to the edges of the graph, but the flow has a value that indicates how much is flowing from $s$ to $t$.

There are [algorithms you can run](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) to calculate the flow network, and then see what the value is.

In your example, the top graph shows the capacities of each edge, and the bottom graph shows a max flow.  The edge with 3 on it has a capacity of three, but in the given max flow, it can only transmit 1.  We could come up with another max flow where it transmits two, but since $t$ only has an incoming capacity of 2, there's no max flow where that edge can transmit 3.

To think about capacities, imagine edges as pipes,  with a size defined by their capacity.  An edge with a capacity of 3 can transmit three units of stuff from one vertex to another.  So if there's only one unit of stuff going through that edge in a max flow, it means that capacity in the network is limited somewhere else.

Wikipedia has decent writeups on [flow networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network) and [max flow problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem).

Comment: I'm sure that your answer is great (I will valide and up vote your answer when I'll totally understand every thing. So don't worry about that :-)). Could you tell me intuitively what you call by "capacity" ? I have a definition in my book, but I don't see exactly what it is. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: @idm gave it a shot.  If you want we can drop into chat and edit the results into the answer.

Comment: It would be a pleasure to me. Tomorrow is fine to you ? It's time to me to sleep. Thanks a lot and sweet dreams :-)

Comment: @Idm I'm in http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24186/why-no-upvotes if you need more clarification.

Comment: Just moved to http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18279/cryptography-and-coding-graph-and-design-theory

Comment: I just have seen your message. Tomorrow is fine ? :-)

Comment: @idm sure, I should be in there most of the day.